# Showing that there are always pairwise energy states for delta potential given $\frac{m \alpha a}{\hbar^2}\gg1$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I have seen many variations of this problem and seen many solutions, but I have not seen anything that can help me in my particular problem it seems. The problem I have is that I do not know how to show that for $\frac{ma\alpha}{\hbar^2}\gg1$ we have 2 very close solutions for the energy-states. I have included the work I have done and would be very thankful for any help.
The problem is the following:

Given the potential $V(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha \delta(x-a)& 0<x<2a\\ \infty & \text{else}\end{cases}$

first derive solutions for the stationary Schrödinger-equation and state the transcendental equation.
So given a hint we had to use functions

$\phi(x)\begin{cases}\phi_1(x)=A_1\sin(kx+\varphi_1) & 0<x<a\\\phi_2(x)=A_2\sin(kx+\varphi_2) & a<x<2a\end{cases}$

I first got rid of the $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$, since the wave-functions have to vanish at the boundaries. You get $\varphi_1=n\pi$ and $\varphi_2=-2ka+n\pi$ if you evaluate the functions at $x=0$ and $x=2a$.

We also have continuity of $\phi$ at $x=a$ so: $$ A_1\sin(ka)=A_2\sin(-ka) \iff \frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{\sin(-ka)}{\sin(ka)}=-1$$
The peak at $x=a$ will make the derivative however discontinuous. Integrating the Schrödinger-equation over a small intervall [$a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon$] and taking the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ will eventually give you:
$$ \phi_2^{'}(a)-\phi_1^{'}(a)=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\alpha \phi(a)$$
Here I put everything on the RHS and now take into account that the function is continuous at $x=a$ so I take $\phi(a)=\phi_2(a)=-A_2sin(ka)$ here and after putting everything I got into the equation:
$$  kA_2cos(ka)-kA_1cos(ka)=\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\alpha A_2\sin(ka) $$
Dividing by $A_2$ and afterwards by $2cos(ka)$ we get:
$$ k=\frac{m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\tan(ka)$$
I thought I simply need to plot the two functions and look for points they will coincide, but forgot that $\tan(x)>x, \quad x \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Do I need to replace $k$ by $\sqrt{\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}E}$ and solve for $E$ on one side? Because I do not see that for $\frac{ma\alpha}{\hbar^2}\gg1$ we have 2 very close solutions for the energy states since I do not seem to see where I have to use this?

Any hint or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you forgot the case $ka = n \pi$, with $n$ integer.

Comment: I noticed I made a mistake, that is when I wanted to get rid of $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$: $\sin(kx+n\pi)\neq\sin(kx)$ if $n$ is odd but will simply give you too many cases which are unnecassary. However if $ka=n\pi$ the continuity condition is fullfilled and the discontinuity equation will give you that the RHS is $0$ and so must the LHS giving you $A_1=A_2$ leaving me no information what so all, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: You do not need other information: you found a new class of solutions, where the energies are given by $k a=\sqrt{2mE a^2/\hbar^2}=n\pi$. Now look at the equation which defines the energies of the class you found before, written as $\tan k a = (m\alpha a/\hbar^2)^{-1} k a$  in the limit $m\alpha a/\hbar^2\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: A better understanding can be obtained by traslating the coordinate by $-a$. You have a even potential, and you expect even and odd eigenfunctions...

Comment: So basically $E_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma^2}$ and with the second equation if $ka=n\pi$ you have $\tan(ka)=0=\frac{1}{\frac{m\alpha a}{\hbar^2}}ka$ and as $\frac{1}{\frac{m\alpha a}{\hbar^2}}$ is very big, $ka$ has to be close to $0$ and plugging in for $k$ we have that $E_n$ is very small. Maybe a bit much of text for a comment but would that be a correct conclusion?

Comment: $E_n = \frac{n^2 \pi^2 \hbar^2}{2 m a^2}$ are the energies for the solutions $k a = n \pi$. These are eigenfunctions with a node in $x=a$, which are unaffected by the potential. The solutions you found initially are different, and the energies can be found  from $\tan u = \beta u$ where $\beta=(m\alpha a/\hbar^2)^{-1}$ and $u=ka$. Graphically it is evident that when $\beta$ is small $u=n \pi + \epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_n$ is a small correction that you can calculate.

Comment: I think I see it now, when you plot $\beta u$ with a very small $\beta$, it basically becomes a straight line almost being the constant $f=0$. And as $tan(u)=0$ for $u=n\pi$ we can conclude that they intersect at $u=n\pi+\epsilon_n$. So all that is left to do would be to rearrange it for $\epsilon_n$ or rather $E_n$, right?

Comment: Yes. You can do it solving for $\tan (n \pi + \epsilon_n) = \beta (n \pi + \epsilon_n)$. This is equivalent for small $\beta$ and small $\epsilon_n$ to $\tan \epsilon_n \simeq n \pi \beta$ or $\epsilon_n \simeq n \pi \beta$.